# Uncountable set of estimates on conditional expectations.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X, Y$ and $Z$ be real-valued integrable random variables. If we assume that for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ $$\mathbb{E}\left[ X   \middle| Z = r\right] > \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \middle|Z =r \right],$$
do we necessarily have $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] > \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \right]$?

This would seem natural, and if the condition would be replaced by something that would partition the probability space countably, there would be no problem. However I'm not really sure how to handle the $\sigma$-algebra generated by events $Z=r$.

Comment: You seem to have in mind cases when P(Z=r)=0. How do you define E(X|Z=r) then? (The way to define it I can think of makes the answer to your question obvious, hence my query.)

Comment: What I guess that happens is the following: events Z=r generate a sub-sigma-algebra F of all events. We then examine the conditional expectations E(X|F) and E(Y|F). These are F-measurable so they remain constant in the sets corresponding to events Z=r. For these constant values we have the estimate above.

Comment: What you guess is not correct. Better to get hold of a textbook explaining conditional expectations in the general case, which, unlike in the countable case, does not and cannot rely on sub-sigma-algebras generated by partitions.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestions on a good reference?

Comment: David Williams, *Probability with martingales*. Short book, a gem.